# supersized stop resizing

Tags: jquery, supersized

I'm using [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) jQuery plugin. My images are `1600x672`, but it always resize them to `1423x597` (to fit the screen).

But I don't want this feature! I want my images in real size, but if the screen size is smaller than 1600px, the image centered horizontally...

It's my configuration:

```
slideshow: 1,
slide_interval: 3000,
transition: 1,
transition_speed: 700,
vertical_center: 0,
horizontal_center: 1,
slide_links: false,
slides: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [**Supersized Docs**](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#min_height), you can preset both `minimum width` and `minimum height` so it will not resize smaller.